# Android Studio Adding Multiple Views to Detail Fragment of Master Detail Template

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am learning Android Programming and I need help. I have created a project in Android Studio and I am using the Master Detail Template. The list is people and the detail should be information about the people such as their name and birthdate and other info. By default, the fragment_person_detail file just has a TextView with an id of person_detail.

```html
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/person_detail"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="16dp" android:textIsSelectable="true"
    tools:context=".PersonDetailFragment" />
```

Also included in the template is an activity_person_detail that has a frame layout for the fragment

```html
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/person_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PersonDetailActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

So, since the layout is in a separate file, I am confused as to how to add another textview to the fragment. When I try, it tells me that I have multiple root tags.

I would like to have a Textview for birthdate for example, so how can I accomplish this?

Here is my PersonDetailFragment

```html
public class PersonDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the item ID that this fragment
     * represents.
     */
    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

    /**
     * The dummy content this fragment is presenting.
     */
    private DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public PersonDetailFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
            // Load the dummy content specified by the fragment
            // arguments. In a real-world scenario, use a Loader
            // to load content from a content provider.
            mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_person_detail, container, false);

        // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
        if (mItem != null) {
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.person_detail)).setText(mItem.content);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.person_age)).setText(mItem.birthdate);
        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

So in towards the end of that file, you can see that I want to reference a TextView with the id of person_age.

But now I am getting the following error

```html
05-06 20:43:42.160  14205-14205/com.dwarwick.finalproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dwarwick.finalproject, PID: 14205
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.x.finalproject/com.x.finalproject.PersonDetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at com.dwarwick.finalproject.PersonDetailFragment.onCreateView(PersonDetailFragment.java:58)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5953)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

since I made the following change.

```html
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/person_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PersonDetailActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/person_birthdate"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="16dp" android:textIsSelectable="true"
        tools:context=".PersonDetailFragment" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

So, in addition to changing the Activity layout as suggested, I also had to modify PersonDetailFragment.java as follows

```html
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_person_detail, container, false);
        //View textview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_person_detail, container, false);

        // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
        if (mItem != null) {
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.person_detail)).setText(mItem.content);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.person_age)).setText(mItem.birthdate);
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is looking for a textview with an id of person_age and then setting a value to it. Your layout only has a single element in it now (person_detail), so you need to add a second textview with an id of person_age.

You might also want to change your parent to a RelativeLayout, so you can position to two textviews easier. try updated layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/person_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".PersonDetailActivity" 
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <TextView         
        android:id="@+id/person_age"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="16dp" 
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView         
        android:id="@+id/person_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/person_age"
        android:padding="16dp" 
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So basically now all of my Views are in activity_person_detail and I am not using the fragment_person_detail. See my edit above for the final code that worked.